# Differences between .Net TcpClient and PHP socket functions

Tags: c#, php, sockets

The original code is written in C# using the `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` class to connect and interact with a socket.

I try to port that code to PHP 7 using basic socket functions (`socket_create`, `socket_connect`, etc.). Connecting to the socket poses no problem. However, I do not get any response when writing (the same data as the C# is sending) to the socket.

Does anybody know if there is any significant difference between a connection created with `TcpClient` and the PHP socket functions?

Comment: Are you sure `socket_create` and `socket_connect` are using the Tcp protocol? In C#, `Sockets` are just an interface to send and receive network messages. If it is the same in PHP, you have to implement the Tcp protocol (or better, use the probably already existing implementation)

Comment: @fharreau, thanks for your comment. To the best of my knowledge - yes, I'm using TCP. The socket in PHP is created as follows: `socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)`. This means an IPv4 based (`AF_INET`), full-duplex, connection-based byte stream (`SOCK_STREAM`), TCP (`SOL_TCP `) socket ... as I understand the official docs on php.net.

Comment: I am sorry, I came here only because of C#, I don't know PHP. You are saying that the connection succeed. How do you assert that? Assuming you are developing the client, are you sure your messages arrive to the server? Do you know if your server is responding to your messages? Check the server's logs if you can or run a software like Wireshack to spy the network.